# How to import a static member of a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to import a static member of a class into a file by just using standard import syntax. To give context:

### Destructuring works on the static method of a class:

```
class Person {
    static walk() {
        console.log('Walking');
    }
}

let {walk} = Person;
console.log(walk); // walk function
```

---

However, I thought imports behaved like destructuring assignments. If that's true, then I would expect the following to work. But, when I attempt to import the walk method, it just comes back as `undefined`:

### Destructuring through imports, why doesn't it work?

---

**`person.js`**

```
export default class Person {
    static walk() {
        console.log('Walking');
    }
}
```

---

**`walker.js`**

```
import {walk} from './person';
console.log(walk); // undefined
```

---

Since this doesn't seem to work, how can I import a static method from a class to another module?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, yeah, doing the imports feels like it falls under that common practice, but for some reason, when I attempt import just the static method, I always get undefined

Comment: After some research it seems you are using `export default` which is different than what I was talking about.

Comment: Generally if you don't need to import the whole constructor, you might as well export the function as a named export instead of making it static, then you can import it like you want to. I see the usecases for static methods as pretty minimal much of the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`export default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) can be mixed with normal exports in ES6. For example :

```
// module-a.js
export default a = 1;
export const b = 2;

// module-b.js
import a, { b } from "./module-a";
a === 1;
b === 2;
```

This means that the import brackets are not the same as a [destructor assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

What you want to achieve is actually not possible in the ES6 specs. Best way to do it, would be to use the destructuring after your import

```
import Person from "./person";
const { walk } = Person;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using is actually a named import, not a destructuring assignment, although they look similar. There is no destructuring import in ES6. All you can do is to add a destructuring assignment to the next line, but keep in mind that this will break when the imports are cyclic.

```
import Person from './person';
const { walk } = Person;
console.log(walk);
```